# Issues submitting form with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have been trying to submit a form with jquery ajax but have been having issues. 
When i check through firebug i see the value posted but it shows error from the url. I have this html

```
<form method="post" name="tForm" id="tForm">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Age</td>
<td><input name="age" id="age" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

My js file that submits the form has this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tForm').submit(function(){
var age = $('#age').val();
var msg ='';

$.ajax({
url:'testp.php',
type:'post',
data: {age:age},
beforeSend:function(){
alert(age);
},
success:function(data){
msg=data;
alert(msg);
},
complete:function(){
alert(msg);
}
})
})
});
```

My testp.php file just has this

```
<?php
echo 'ok';
?>
```

Comment: "it shows an error"? The nature of the error might be useful to know.

Comment: What response code are you getting? `data: {age:age}` <- this seems destined for trouble, I'd put the first reference in quotes.

Comment: It doesn't show error one might understand just the POST url in red

Comment: I dont get any response code just the POST url in red

Comment: Why don't you indent your code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the event from propogating.  Your form attempts to submit in the standard method and since your form doesn't have an action you receive the error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tForm').submit(function(){
    var age = $('#age').val();
    var msg ='';

    $.ajax({
    url:'testp.php',
    type:'post',
    data: {age:age},
    beforeSend:function(){
    alert(age);
    },
    success:function(data){
    msg=data;
    alert(msg);
    },
    complete:function(){
    alert(msg);
    }
    })
    return false;
    })
    });
```

Comment: I added the event.StopPropagation(); line but i get event not defined error

Comment: sorry i corrected it but it still behaves the same way as before

Comment: you are welcome but do you know why my success function will not alert msg from my php

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#tForm').submit(function(e){ ...` and then call `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the form from being submitted in a regular (non-ajax) request.

However, I'd suggest you to have a look at the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) which saves you some work.